# How to calculate and detect PanResponder event?

Tags: react-native, animation

I am pretty new to animation and gesture handler. I am reading the documentation in the official react native animations and I found a snippet of this code that lets you move around the blue box.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/animations

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { Animated, View, StyleSheet, PanResponder, Text } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
  const pan = useRef(new Animated.ValueXY()).current;
  const panResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
        null,
        { dx: pan.x, dy: pan.y }
      ]),
      onPanResponderRelease: () => {
        Animated.spring(pan, { toValue: { x: 0, y: 0 } }).start();
      }
    })
  ).current;

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.titleText}>Drag & Release this box!</Text>
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          transform: [{ translateX: pan.x }, { translateY: pan.y }]
        }}
        {...panResponder.panHandlers}
      >
        <View style={styles.box} />
      </Animated.View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  titleText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    lineHeight: 24,
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
  box: {
    height: 150,
    width: 150,
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    borderRadius: 5
  }
});

export default App;
```

However, I want to console.log or do sone calculations when panresponder move so I tried  modifying my opPanResponderMove but the blue box doesnt move anymore. I was wondering why?

My modified code:

```
onPanResponderMove: (event, gestureState) => {
        console.log(event);
        console.log(gestureState);
        Animated.event([
            null,
            { dx: pan.x, dy: pan.y }
          ])
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue about your problem [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15880)

It said that

> Reason was because Animation.event() only generates the function which is used from onPanResponderMove, it also needs the default arguments evt, gestureState

and here is the fix:

```js
onPanResponderMove: (event, gestureState) => {
        console.log(event);
        console.log(gestureState);
        return Animated.event([
            null,
            { dx: pan.x, dy: pan.y }
          ])(event,gestureState);
      },
```